# How can I change the color of externally imported SVG in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg, dynamic, import, colors

It is easy to change a color of SVG if you have it available internally. Is there a way to change an SVG's color that comes from the server?

Here is the example. You can fork it.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StyledApp>
      {/* <HomeIcon /> */}
      {/* <img
        src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alieliacik/2df2a5fdf5b5c707f8dac91f390e01a1/raw/840c8efb0374ac0c3912dc36646abf0a9798832b/try.svg"
        alt="aa"
      /> */}

      <Svg src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alieliacik/2df2a5fdf5b5c707f8dac91f390e01a1/raw/840c8efb0374ac0c3912dc36646abf0a9798832b/try.svg" />
    </StyledApp>
  );
};

export default App;

const StyledApp = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const Svg = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  mask: ${({ src }) => `url(${src}) no-repeat `};
  mask-size: 80px 80px;
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/global-theming-dynamic-icon-0npro?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Are you trying to change the SVG, or are you ok with just using it as a mask and changing the background color to give the "illusion" that it's been changed? From what I can tell playing around in your sandbox, no, you can't change the svg styling since it's essentially imported as an image.

Comment: I can't open your sand box example as it freezes my machine. But if you provide the code just here in a snnipet I may help you because I think i can manage to change its color no matter it it is imported or local.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the style of the SVG when it's imported as an image. If you examine the DOM you'll see why.

```
<div src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alieliacik/
  2df2a5fdf5b5c707f8dac91f390e01a1/raw/
  840c8efb0374ac0c3912dc36646abf0a9798832b/try.svg"
  class="sc-ikXwFM luKyi"
></div>
```

There is nothing to target other than the `div` tag itself.

From your sandbox you are using the fetched SVG as a mask and changing the background color, clever. The issue here though is that you are using `styled-components` and styling a div.

```
const Svg = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  mask: ${({ src }) => `url(${src}) no-repeat center`};
`;
```

If you instead render an `svg` element, you'll see what you were attempting appears to work.

```
const Svg = styled.svg`
  background-color: green;
  mask: ${({ src }) => `url(${src}) no-repeat center`};
`;
```

[image]

I'd give it a more manageable height/width though.

```
const Svg = styled.svg`
  width: 1.5rem; // base 24px x 24px
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: green;
  mask: ${({ src }) => `url(${src}) no-repeat center`};
`;
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-change-the-color-of-externally-imported-svg-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

You can change svg colour if you add the HTML  element inside the component.
For instance in this SVG wave, you can change the fill attribute here and the colour will change.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,197.3C384,171,480,149,576,165.3C672,181,768,235,864,250.7C960,267,1056,245,1152,250.7C1248,256,1344,288,1392,304L1440,320L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
```

Or the code above can be saved in a file as wave.svg. Then you can change the fill colour, import the file and use in React component as,

```
 import wave from '../wave.svg'


 const Component=()=>{

   return(

    <div>
     <img src={wave}/>
    </div>


 )
}
```

Or you can inspect the icon's link, you will find the  code and copy it to a file and import it. The code in your svg link is

```
<svg width="17px" height="19px" viewBox="0 0 17 19" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 3.8.1 (29687) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>home [#1393]</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" fill="yellow" >
    <g id="Dribbble-Light-Preview" transform="translate(-341.000000, -720.000000)" >
        <g id="icons" transform="translate(56.000000, 160.000000)">
            <path d="M299.875,576.21213 C299.875,576.76413 299.399,577.00013 298.8125,577.00013 L297.75,577.00013 C297.1635,577.00013 296.6875,576.76413 296.6875,576.21213 L296.6875,575.21213 C296.6875,574.10713 295.736562,573.00013 294.5625,573.00013 L292.4375,573.00013 C291.263438,573.00013 290.3125,574.10713 290.3125,575.21213 L290.3125,576.21213 C290.3125,576.76413 289.8365,577.00013 289.25,577.00013 L288.1875,577.00013 C287.601,577.00013 287.125,576.76413 287.125,576.21213 L287.125,568.14913 C287.125,568.01613 287.181312,567.88913 287.280125,567.79513 L292.738188,562.65913 C293.153625,562.26813 293.826188,562.26813 294.240563,562.65913 L299.719875,567.81513 C299.818688,567.90913 299.875,568.03613 299.875,568.16813 L299.875,576.21213 Z M302,567.62513 C302,567.36013 301.888438,567.10713 301.690812,566.91913 L294.998125,560.58913 C294.169375,559.80613 292.823188,559.80313 291.99125,560.58313 L285.312375,566.84813 C285.112625,567.03613 285,567.29013 285,567.55613 L285,577.21213 C285,578.31713 285.950938,579.00013 287.125,579.00013 L290.3125,579.00013 C291.486562,579.00013 292.4375,578.31713 292.4375,577.21213 L292.4375,576.21213 C292.4375,575.66013 292.9135,575.21213 293.5,575.21213 C294.0865,575.21213 294.5625,575.66013 294.5625,576.21213 L294.5625,577.21213 C294.5625,578.31713 295.513438,579.00013 296.6875,579.00013 L299.875,579.00013 C301.049062,579.00013 302,578.31713 302,577.21213 L302,567.62513 Z" id="home-[#1393]"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

I have changed the fill and stroke colour to yellow. It will change the colour on display.

Comment: The SVG isn't a local asset; it's fetched from a server.